# Using specific online map as basemap in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, basemap

The following link contains data which I want to display them as basemap in ArcMap for further investigations,

Could you help me to do that?

http://cadastre.mimt.gov.ir/Map/Map.aspx?PNid=0

Comment: Can you please give more information about what you are trying to accomplish? Do you want the map to just be an image below your data? Do you want to be able to manipulate the data displayed on the map?

Comment: @Sammy
I want to Display the content of that map as a georefrenced image in background as a basemap. Just like way that you use the website in your browser. I want to check my data with the data in that map.

Comment: @Sammy
Your solution is not appropriate. This is time consuming and is not rapid.

You can screenshot the map and save it as a png and then georeference it as in this tutorial: http://gpshort.uga.edu/instructions/gis/Georeference%20an%20image%20using%20ArcMap.pdf

If you need to be able to see a greater level of detail, then take a series of overlapping screenshots over the zoomed in map and then georeference each screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can screenshot the map and save it as a png and then georeference it as in this tutorial: http://gpshort.uga.edu/instructions/gis/Georeference%20an%20image%20using%20ArcMap.pdf

If you need to be able to see a greater level of detail, then take a series of overlapping screenshots over the zoomed in map and then georeference each screenshot.